# Do people see my losses in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I have been playing Dota 2 for awhile. I checked some of my friend's profile and I only see the Wins. Is there a option to let others see my losses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default people **can't** see your losses.

However if you have enabled **Share Match History** in options,people will be able to see your losses(and even more stats) on the online sites like [dotabuff](http://dotabuff.com/) by searching for your name(no matter if friends or not).

Answer (score 5):

Nobody but you can see the number of your losses or abandoned games in your in-game profile and there is no way to change it.

By the way, since [July 26, 2013](http://dota2wiki.com/July_26,_2013_Patch) wins and level are also hidden from non-friends by default:

> Wins and level are now hidden for players that aren't friends and don't have 'Share Match History' in the options enabled

However, as *Arremer* [reminds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/125833) us, with enabled Match History, third-party websites can show many different statistics. For example, [DotaBuff](http://dotabuff.com/search) shows your win/loss ratio and the number of games that you played while "Share Match History" was enabled.